# accessing method like get in didInsertElement of view

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

im trying to using jquery drag and drop and i want to using some tools of ember in my view but i cant .

```
App.myView = Ember.View.extend({
tagName:'li',
didInsertElement:function(){
    this.$().draggable({
    start:function(event,ui){
    console.log(this.get('tagName'));
    } 
  });
 }
});
```

but i get an error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLLIElement> has no method 'get'
```

can i use methods like get/set or other in didInsertElement in jquery section ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` inside the jQuery draggable initialization object does not refer to the view anymore, therefore you should first store `this` in a local variable like `self` so you can use it later on, try this:

```
App.myView = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName:'li',
  didInsertElement:function(){
    var self = this;
    this.$().draggable({
      start:function(event,ui){
        console.log(self.get('tagName'));
      } 
    });
  }
});
```

Hope it helps.